# How to prevent changes in Directories after UISequence

Tags: wix

I am linking my product with other libraries, trying to make it easier to install a set of directories in multiple installations. The purpose is to reuse the xml code, problem is they have to be installed in the Root directory per customer requirement.

So I have my `ComponentGroup`s inside the WixLibrary.

I set up my directories in the Wix Application.

But after `CostFinalize` just before Installation the Directories are reset to their default values and not the ones chosen by my user during the Dialogs Sequence.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, First things first:

- The problem is that after `CostFinalize` and all `UI` operations my directories where replaced with the default values.
- The problem started when I linked two different libraries that used the same global directory.
- The folder is set in the root folder of Windows (Per customer Requirement) and then set up to a default value. Then we attach a  `Property` just like we would do it for the `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR`, overall we have the following:

  - One `root` folder for the specific files of the installer
  - A library that installs files to 4 `directories` that are unrelated to that `root` directory.
  - Another library that installs files and runs scripts to 1 `directory` of those 4 external `directories`. This library is the only specifc to our install.

> Linking all that is a problem of its own, it has to be done in the `Product`, in the `UI`, and using the `PropertyRef`specified in the external library. Furthermore, keep in mind that every `PathEdit` has to be set to `Indirect="yes"`, and you have to set all indirect `Properties` that point to your `Directory` in the `UI`

To fix the problem is really simple, `Microsoft Installer` rechecks all our folders after the user has set them up during the Install Sequence, so we need to prevent any changes after the user has changed it during the `UI Sequence`. Thus `Properties` to the rescue.

Here is an example, in the `UI` you set a freeze folders to each folder you want to set in the `InstallUISequence`

```
<Property Id="SETFOLDERFREEZE">0</Property>
<CustomAction Id="caSetPreventChanges" Property="SETFOLDERFREEZE" Value="1"/>
```

Then in your `Product` you link that property.

```
<PropertyRef Id="SETFOLDERFREEZE"/>
<SetDirectory Id="SPECIFIC_FOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]MoreStuff" Sequence="both">
   <![CDATA[SETFOLDERFREEZE<>"1"]]>
</SetDirectory>
<Property Id="EXTRAFILES_INSTALLDIR" Value="SPECIFIC_FOLDER"/>
```

You use the `Property` `EXTRAFILES_INSTALLDIR` in your specific `UI` for that project and you use `SPECIFIC_FOLDER` in your reusable `Library`.

It's a mess... but allows reusability, and setting some simple properties and custom actions beats setting up the Files and Folders all over again, specially if there are hundreds of them.